# How to use ez_image_alias using twig

Tags: twig, ezpublish

I wanna use ez_image_alias() function but I dunno what values I have to put in.

Do you have some examples of how to use this function using Twig ?

Comment: [`ez_image_alias`](https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/ez_image_alias)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ez_image_alias` Twig function accepts three parameters:

- field you wish to render
- version info of the content where the field is located
- variant name

Starting from your content which is available in a `content` variable in your template, you would use `ez_image_alias` function like this:

```
{% set variation = ez_image_alias(
    ez_field(content, 'image'),
    content.versionInfo,
    'large')
%}
```

`variation` variable will now hold an instance of `eZ\Publish\SPI\Variation\Values\ImageVariation` object which you can use to render the image:

`<img src="{{ asset(variation.uri) }}" />`

Comment: Nothing to add, perfect answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching, thank you very much :)